# Normal Maps seem to be baked with Low Poly Details

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map, unreal-engine

**UPDATE:**

[image]
Tried my best to retopo the thing a bit more clean and twist the Y for DirectX.
Maybe I have to practice topology, because the result seems still underwhelming, it doesn't look like the sculpt by any means. :/

---

**OLD:**

I am trying to get a normal map from a high poly torso and get it on the low poly model in Unreal. I checked the Bake Settings, tried different solutions for the base mesh, the end result always looks like this:

[image: description]

It seems to be a combination between the low and the high poly model.

But the idea is to get only the surface of the high poly model, right? Or am I completely wrong and I simply can't hide the low poly surface?
On top of the above, I've tried numerous things. Subdivision helps, but it only looks good if I set it to 6+ and then every performance + for games is gone and the whole normal map thing is redundant.

The red circles show a few edges that are slightly "off", but they don't seem to be responsible for the overall bad quality of the map.

The lines that I marked in the purple normal map image are exactly those from the low poly object. What are they doing there?

PS: Maybe the problem is that the low poly mesh is wrapped around the high poly? I thought it is good this way but maybe it has to be the other way around?

Comment: your topology is very bad is the first part of your problem, correct this and try again

Comment: you have acute angles in a pessimistic topology, and that causes those low poly marks

Comment: It is not exactly an answer but it will serve as a guide to improve your modeling which is horrible [reference image bad topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqgHQ.png)

Comment: ok, thank you for your critique. I hope to get it right, good topology means that the faces are connected in a more "straight matter", so that all the edges traverse the whole object in a straight line? That means i have to add quite a few lines I think...

Comment: you don't need too many vertices, just a little more, I have some examples that will help you a lot [Check this pic](https://static.turbosquid.com/Preview/2019/01/26__06_48_20/01.pngC7854ED4-4D88-4E2B-92DF-1AA2C276D13EDefault.jpg)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kyytI0lx0g

Comment: Ok, I improved mine a bit. now everything looks more streamlined (only symmetric squares in the UV wrap), but I still use too many vertices in spots that don't need them. The guy in the video has some serious skill ongoing about staying minimalistic. He uses a lot of triangles, which I heard they shouldn't be used natively... Thx for your impressions, hope I will get better with this in time...:)

Comment: Updated my question with the new result. Definitly better, but far from the look of the sculpt. :/ I assume I have to practice topology a lot more :S

Comment: try with this https://youtu.be/aAO4C_8y0w8

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that you are baking a normal map suited for OpenGl. Unreal uses DirectX normal maps. You can easily solve this by inverting the green channel. It can be done during bake in blender, in photoshop or in Unreal in the material.

[image]

The dark scene in Cycles needs some lights to be useful. But if you need to have it shown correctly with the DirectX normal maps you need to invert the green channel in the material.

The next problem you have, is the artefact which is caused by a very thin triangle. (Even it you don't see triangles, all faces will be split into triangles during rendering and baking.) When the normal bends over the face and there aren't enough pixels the baker will not be able to create that bend without aliasing. The fastest way of fixing this is to give that face more room on the UV map. That would increase the resolution for that area only. But the better way would be to avoid thin triangles.

Comment: Updated my question with new results, but still I am not happy. The result simply doesn't look as the sculpt. I tried to improve the topology, it helped a bit. Maybe I have tu practice more to achieve a nice result. :S